# Windows 2000 Server IIS FTP user log

Tags: iis, logging, ftp

Is there an easy way to look at some type of log or anything that will show what users have been on the box within a certain time frame. We are retiring the box and need to see if turning it off will make anyone mad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the server, go to %WinDir%\System32\LogFiles

All the IIS log files are in here and are in folders beginning W3SVC... (all FTP sites are MSFTPSVC...)

Comment: Make sure logging is turned on for the FTP server in its properties too.

Answer (score 2):

turn it off, see who calls. If they can't tell you why they need it leave it off until you hear from their boss. repeat question and response until they give up or reach a high enough boss level.

*WARNING* this is an advanced admin technique that takes years of experience to pull off, your boss may not feel you have enough experience for this method. But it certainly works.

Comment: I would love to +1 this...  Best practice, however, forbids me.

Comment: I don't think I will ever have enough pull to do this where I work. The president is already pissed enough at our flaky email server. +1 for the morning laugh. Thanks!